# ScrollView scroll position updates too late

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, scrollview

I have a CarouselView which changes it's ItemTemplate according to the item being viewed:

```
<!--Alarm Event UI-->
        <CarouselView x:Name="cvAlarmEvents"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding AlarmEvents}"
                      CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedAlarmEvent}"
                      CurrentItemChangedCommand="{Binding CmdSelectedAlarmEventChanged}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AlarmEventDataTemplateSelector}"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"
                      BackgroundColor="#141d3d"                      
                      IsVisible="true"
                      Scrolled="CvAlarmEventsOnScrolled" />
```

Each DataTemplate is a ContentView with a ScrollView as the parent. (I've seen it plastered across documentation that it's not advisable to nest a scrollview inside any other scrollable layout, but what else can I do when I need to be able to scroll between items and each item must have scrollable content also)

```
<!--ContentView used in one of my DataTemplates-->
<ScrollView x:Name="scrollAe"
                Margin="0, 7, 0, 0"
                BackgroundColor="#141d3d">
                

        <!--Lots of lovely content-->

    </ScrollView>
```

Let's say the user scrolls vertically on an item, then they swipe the CarouselView to the next item, then lets say they swipe back to the previous item, the scrollY of the first item should be reset to 0. The only method I can see which allows you to programatically change the scroll position of a ScrollView is:

```
ScrollToAsync(0, 0, false);
```

The problem is, it doesn't update until the user scrolls back to the previous item, at which point the user can see the scroll position reset take place, which is not what I want. It should be reset before the user scrolls back to it. Here is my current attempt and it simply is not working. Sometimes it works, maybe 1/5 times, but it is in no way consistent I've tried an assortment of invoking it on the main thread and forcing the layout.

```
private async void OnScrollReset(object sender, Events.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (scrollAe.ScrollY > 0)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
                {
                    await scrollAe.ScrollToAsync(0, 0, false);
                });

                scrollAe.ForceLayout();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The ScrollView class derives from the Layout class, you should not put ScrollView 
 to CarouselView. And ScrollView objects should not be nested with other controls that provide scrolling.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview

Comment: I'm aware of this, I already mentioned it in my question.

Comment: Can you share a demo about this issue, I cannot produce this issue at 1/5 times works.